# Sharepoint 2019 custom WCF service shows me "type not found"

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, wcf

Once i've created custom web extension for another SP farm, and had no troubles here, still works, but now i don't know  where else to dig.
I follow  well-know tutorial - https://jbarkes.blogspot.com/2014/04/sharepoint-2013-create-custom-wcf-rest.html

And i cannot call a simpliest get-method, the error is:

*The type 'WEBExt.UnlockService, WEBExt, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive, or provided in the configuration element system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations could not be found.*

My service looks like:
UnlockService.svc.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using WEBExt.Models;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WEBExt
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class UnlockSerivce : IUnlockService
    { 
        public string Hi()
        { return "Hi!"; }       
    }
}
```

IUnlockService.cs:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using WEBExtExt.Models;

namespace WEBExt { 

    [ServiceContract]
    interface IUnlockService
    {   
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "GET", UriTemplate = "Hi")]
        string Hi();
    }
}
```

IUnlockService.cs:

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language = "C#" Debug="true"
    Service="WEBExt.UnlockService, $SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$"
    CodeBehind="UnlockService.svc.cs"    Factory="Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Services.MultipleBaseAddressWebServiceHostFactory,
    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ServerRuntime, Version = 16.0.0.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

The service dll is deployed to GAC just as referenced dll's.

i've got very strange this in my logs:

*w3wp.exe (0x4050)  0x0D80  SharePoint Foundation   Claims Authentication   af32k   Medium  Claims Windows Sign-In: Sending 401 for request 'https://mysp/_vti_bin/UnlockService.svc/Hi' because the user is not authenticated and resource requires authentication.    4d6c17a0-1874-106e-1652-adb5c775fbe2
w3wp.exe (0x4050)   0x0D80  SharePoint Foundation   General b6p2    Medium  Sending HTTP response 401 - text/plain:401 UNAUTHORIZED.    4d6c17a0-1874-106e-1652-adb5c775fbe2*

Browser didn't ask for credentials. I'm guessing this may be configuration issue but i have no idea what else to check.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

By default, you may need to use HTTP basic auth.

Try adding an Authorization header with `{user}:{password}`.

On our farm, our services automatically look for HTTP basic auth. Not sure how you change this as it is something I'm currently looking into.